# When to downvote/upvote?

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

Say I see a question with -10 votes, and although I don't really like this question, I think it's **not that bad** to receive (at least) 10 downvotes. IMHO, that question should receive a vote of -1 or -2. Then should I downvote it to state my attitude towards the question itself, or upvote it to make it closer to -1/-2?

The ultimate question is: Is it OK to let others' votes affect my decision? And is it OK to downvote/upvote to manipulate the score a question/answer get deliberately?

Comment: [_"In order to be an immaculate member of a flock of sheep, one must above all be a sheep oneself."_](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins165194.html)

Comment: Always, always, always vote on content, never, ever, ever on context.

Comment: If the question is bad... why should you upvote it? seriously? "good" = "upvote". "bad" = "downvote".... nothing else... anyway do the math, since downvotes and upvotes don't give/remove the same amount of point, if you put a question at -10 up to -2..... the OP actually GAINS a lot of rep.... so... let's not make bad users get rep for bad questions...

Answer (score 9):

> The ultimate question is: Is it OK to let others' votes affect my decision?

Why should you let this affect your own decision? You should vote by **judging the contents of the question**, and not what the actual voting score of that question is.

> And is it OK to downvote/upvote to manipulate the score a question/answer get deliberately?

An upvote shouldn't be a counter action for a downvote or vice versa. Just do as mentioned above.