# A person asked me "did you downvote my answer?" Should I reply?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason, behavior

When I saw a wrong answer and that answer got a downvote. I commented on it to suggest improvements. Then, the answerer asked me "**Is that you who downvoted the answer?**".

If you were me in that situation, what would you do?

There are two situations, the first is you're the one who downvoted and the second is you didn't do that. However, in both cases, I feel like I don't need to reply to that kind of question because *it's unfriendly and unkind*.

Comment: Such a question isn't _Unfriendly or unkind_ imo. It's _not needed_, but it's not an insult or attack.

Comment: I think we're not supposed to ask that question, that's not what I expected for suggesting improvements to __a downvoted answer__? I felt so sad about that and I felt like I shouldn't suggest any improvements to __a downvoted answer__ ...I'm afraid...

Comment: People can hold a grudge for a very long time if they suspect you, upvotes last a minute, downvotes last for months.  Tends to matter when you expect to encounter him frequently.   You could say "Not me, I only downvote posts that cannot be improved".

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I know the feeling, but it's best to let it go. If someone goes on a voting spree, becomes rude, etc. we can handle that when the time comes. Usually, nastiness on SO ends with an anticlimax, like it should.

Comment: @HansPassant _"Not me, I only downvote posts that cannot be improved"_ wow! sounds like a mantra for me, I'll use it next time, for sure

Comment: @HansPassant What if that's a lie?

Comment: @SteveSummit It's really not about obsessing; some people will just downvote answers simply because they don't like another user. And typically questions with multiple answers, their answer which can be sufficient enough to answer the question, gets overlooked by another simply because someone doesn't like your name. Not to mention chronic downvoters who will downvote questions/answers simply because there is already a downvote on it.

Comment: Do whatever you want. If you want to answer, answer. If you want to be honest, be honest.

Comment: If you are in trolling mood (you should not be) you can reply "I have not voted, but thanks to bringing importance of votes to my attention. After careful re-reading I found that  you post is missing … and is unlikely to help future visitors because … . As you reminded I'll vote according following https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317307/when-to-downvote-upvote." (for real guidance on what to do in this case - see answers)

Comment: You could respond: O yes, a downvote. I almost forgot, thank you.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder for how long will downvotes remain anonymous with the new *be nice* trend in SE

Comment: "Only downvote posts that cannot be improved"? Does anyone vote this way? Is there a good reason to vote this way?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Regarding _"Such a question isn't Unfriendly or unkind imo"_, I disagree completely; it is hostile. _"Is that you who downvoted the answer?"_ is inherently and needlessly personalizing the discussion, and I see no benign interpretation for such a question. If someone truly cares about being downvoted then state _"I see I have been downvoted. Feedback on why that might have happened will be gratefully received so that I can improve my answer"_. What is a legitimate reason for asking someone if they downvoted? I can't think of any.

Comment: @skomisa a Q like this in a comment can go either way.  I've had many a positive experience that started much like this.  I'll respond "Yes, and here's why..."  the next response from the OP will usually produce either a flag and walk away,  or a constructive exchange of ideas.  (I see no overt hostility in this comment.  If there is, just flag and walk away)

Comment: Unlike meta, on the main site, "comments are not for extended discussion", so not only is the question off topic, any reply would also be. So what is the point of replying if both messages should be flagged for deletion?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

> If you were me in that situation, what would you do?

Ignore the comment, disengage. Respond to requests to clarify your suggestion for improvements only. Do not disclose how you voted.

Additionally, flag the comment as "no longer needed", since it is pure noise.

Comment: Why not tell them? I would. If they start to get angry about it, then you can disengage, but you might as well tell them, unless they're already being hostile.

Comment: @TheWanderer you can do that, of course, but it's not advised. People rarely react well to these things.

Comment: I haven't ever had an issue with it. If I see a downvoted question and the OP asking why it was downvoted, I'll say something like "I didn't downvote, but people might've downvoted because..." If I was one of them, then I would just change the beginning to say why.

Comment: @TheWanderer The problem here isn't that they're asking _why_, they're asking _if_. Asking why someone downvoted could be so they could give a better answer/question, but what purpose would finding out if someone downvoted give?

Comment: @TheWandered With honesty, best scenario; Nothing changes, Worst scenario: Your get a downvote revenge spree, or an harasser, or whatnot. I don't see a place where it helps you to do it.

Comment: Oh, don't worry about downvote revenge sprees, those usually have no net effect eventually!

Comment: @Patrice Honestly, I did worry about the worst scenario and I really don't know what's right thing to do.

Comment: @TheWanderer: The very fact that they are asking the question probably means they are already upset about the downvote. In such cases, I don't really see that entering into a discussion helps.

Comment: @TheWanderer These days I try to first leave a friendly message explaining what's wrong and pointing to [ask], or whatever. Then I come back a bit later and if the OP has been active but not addressed the issue(s) then I leave the down vote. That way I've already explained why they got the down vote, and if they ask I know there's nothing to be gained by replying.

Comment: @MrLister I've had OPs that revenge down voted in a way that bypassed the automated systems, so I had to get a mod involved. :/

Comment: @AndyJ You mean, a very very slow downvote spree? But how did you know it was the same person each time?

Comment: @MrLister Something along those lines, yeah. (I don't really want to explicitly discuss ways to bypass automated checks!) If you get down votes on multiple questions which have had no activity in a long time (negative or positive) then it's pretty obvious something is going on. Someone is going through your history. I flagged a mod and they fixed it, so they seemingly agreed too.

Comment: @TheWanderer see the voting history on my questions for evidence of what happens when you routinely leave comments on posts you've downvoted. They don't even have to be in response to a "why the downvote" comment.

Comment: @Magisch I've never seen anyone react poorly when I've said that I was not the downvoter.

Comment: Not sure about the 'Additionally, flag the comment as "no longer needed", since it is pure noise.' part.   Think about how it will land to the answerer when their comment disappears-- I imagine, in good faith, that they are asking out of a desire for clarity/transparency, and having such a request simply disappear would feel pretty hostile.

Comment: @DonHatch Comments are already ephemeral by nature, so no one should feel them being removed as an act of hostility. Plus, if someone wanted to provide feedback along with the downvote, very likely would they have had before that comment. Future visitors of the site are not interested in these requests either.

Comment: @Magisch i consider a behaviour like that suggested by you in the answer cruel, arrogant, and unempathic, especially the "no longer needed" part. We are not machines, but humans with feelings. The person who asks feels bad and you definitely worsen it by refusing to communicate. What is the issue with saying: "No, i didnt, but i feel sorry that your post got downvoted. I will give you an upvote if you improve it like <suggestions>." What does it cost you to do that? Nothing. Plus, you may get an improved question. Plus, you may get a friend for life.

Comment: @Nils No.  The risk of someone being more aggressive is much higher than someone being reasonable.  That comes from pure experience, and isn't theoretical.

Comment: @Nils In the context of a question on stack overflow, the thing we're optimising for is quality of questions. It's perfectly possible to leave actionable suggestions for improvement (like I recommend doing in my answer) without disclosing your voting habits. And the "no longer needed" flag is just housekeeping - that comment would be noise for future visitors who come here for a solution, not meta commentary about the voting on a question.

Comment: @Magisch if the person was already aggressive, flagging their comment would almost definitely make them more aggressive. Either respond honestly to the comment or just ignore it, but flagging it is very likely to cause disputes.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd How though? It's not visible who flagged, unless that person comes back to notice their comment gone, it's unlikely they'll even know.

Comment: @Magisch they will surely suspect you, which may be enough to make them aggressive.

Comment: @Nils from Shog9 on [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081): [_"Explaining votes is almost pure noise, meta-conversation and punditry. Your votes are your own to do with as you please; you owe no one an explanation, nor is a discussion of your voting habits likely to be helpful."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777) ... _"indicating that you've downvoted is an extremely bad idea regardless of how you communicate it [...] don't be tricked into thinking it's required or encouraged."_

Comment: Basically... Reply at your own risk. I typically don't reply to them directly, but often they'll be posted as I'm typing up a comment so indirectly i do respond to them. Often people disagree with my reasoning, and that's fine. I do routinely get downvoted seemingly randomly, which sucks, but where I am with reputation that doesn't matter to me so I keep doing what I think is best regardless of the downvotes I receive in response. Sometimes though... i will respond if it's a user i've had previous interactions with who routinely leaves snarky why the downvote comments to return the favor. :)

Comment: @TinyGiant not owing someone an explanation does not mean that i wont give it.

Comment: @Magisch I see the good points in your reply to my comment. It is a good thing to focus on quality of the questions. Still i feel sorry for such people. For these things private messages would be handy, keeping the questions free from this so called 'noise'. I have read some topics at Meta about this and it seems that others think different. Ok. But when SO really wants people to communicate friendlier they should first give them the (optional) possibility to communicate ;-)

Comment: @Nils the point being that it is neither required nor encouraged, and an extremely bad idea regardless of how you communicate it. This point was directed at your demonizing of Magisch's suggestion: _"i consider a behaviour like that suggested by you in the answer cruel, arrogant, and unempathic."_ The behaviour suggested by Magisch in this answer is not cruel, arrogant, or unemphatic, it is the behaviour that is encouraged not only by the system itself but by the community managers. Anonymous voting is built in, no one should be made to feel bad for not divulging their voting habits.

Comment: Well, someone commented here, in a productive manner,  and got lablelled 'cruel, arrogant, and unempathic' for it.  Point proven.  Commenting on downvotes is like a request to look over the parapet to see where the enemy sniper is.

Answer (score 34):

There's a reason why votes are anonymous. You have no obligation to answer.

In all cases, (even if you downvoted, may I add), if you want to help the poster and you may know a possible reason why it got a downvote, you could answer something like this:

> I didn't downvote but your solution doesn't work because ...

although I would reserve that comment to posts that I didn't vote upon and when OP doesn't ping me aggressively like this (never happened to me BTW). But sometimes it allows to cool down and avoids revenge downvotes.

A less "please-forgive-me-for-what-I-didn't-do" way could be (thanks Tiny Giant)

> My guess is that you got downvoted because ...

Another alternative would be to downvote another time, so it shows OP that *several* people find this post not useful. Downvoting for that sole purpose isn't very fair, that said. Downvote if not useful, regardless of comments.

Comment: "Downvoting for that sole purpose isn't very fair" - But if the solution really didn't work then it fully deserves to be downvoted. One might go as far as to say it's your duty to downvote.

Comment: not saying otherwise. I mean if you don't know why someone else downvoted, don't pile it on

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre _"There's a reason why votes are anonymous."_ absolutely, there must be a reason why votes are anonymous and it makes me believe that I should avoid answering the question.

Comment: FWIW, I rather dislike “I didn’t downvote but…” comments. Just leave that aside entirely. I don’t understand why anyone needs to justify themselves regarding their votes.

Comment: They start a sentence with "not my downvote but" because they feel it protects them from abuse. Whether it does protect them is currently unproven AFAIK, but since we know downvotes are often taken personally, this strategy has some reasoning.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú - correct - everyone has indeed now told you, simply IGNORE such a rude question.

Comment: depending on your mood, ignore, or make OP feel bad by explaining that they chose the wrong target. Never happened to me BTW.

Comment: "I didn't downvote" sounds awful. It's *both* noise (a bit less noise than "did you downvote?", but still noise) *and* carries the wrong message (that downvoting is a hostile act).

Comment: it's awful, but widely used, and ... it works :)

Comment: _`"I usually reserve that comment to posts that I didn't vote upon and when OP doesn't ping me aggressively like this."`_ I'd like to know if you fell like  _`"Is that you who downvoted the answer?"`_ is aggressive? Because for me it's not aggressive at all. It's just a question (even if its just a noisy one). I wouldn't feel offended or take it as an aggressive question.

Comment: I find that slightly aggressive. But at least my answer doesn't suggest to brush it off all the time. Someone _has_ to _start_ being nice at some point.

Comment: @deceze: it's extremely obvious why we sometimes have to preface constructive criticism with *“I didn’t downvote but…”*. a) Sometimes the OP is being unfairly downvoted/VtC/harassed with comments/piling-on (this happens quite often; and sometimes it happens for several questions in a row, without a reasonable reason). b) Possibly combined with, or separate to, a) sometimes the OP (especially a new user, but quite often an existing user too) is too defensive about criticism, and not amenable to hearing it, until the commenter establishes both their credibility and their impartiality.

Comment: Then _`"depending on your mood, ignore, or make OP feel bad by explaining that they chose the wrong target. "`_ may not be the right move to go, considering someone _has_ to _start_ being nice at some point.

Comment: ...and c) sometimes the OP's experience is due to being on the wrong end of a downvoting ring through no fault of their own, which you're all aware happens on SO, but I don't see people here acknowledging it.

Comment: downvoting _is_ nice. At list it is not "not nice". But true: downvotes attract downvotes... until it's too much and people start upvoting to make that up.

Comment: @smci Of course I *understand* why people do it, I just think it's pretty silly. It *shouldn't* matter. I always phrase comments in a way that neither suggests nor disallows the possibility that I downvoted. I don't want to talk about that in comments. I want to talk about what can be done to undo the downvotes, period.

Comment: @deceze: yeah, it's always nice to explain why the answer is bad. But a lot of users will interpret "downvote+negative feedback comment" as originating from the same user. Personally I usually prefer to warn the user before downvoting. Sometimes it works and they update/delete their answer without getting a sole downvote

Comment: This is what I do when I see a post that I think can be improved but it has a "Downvoter: please explain your downvote" comment. The comment itself is a trap for all future commenters, because if no one was explaining anything before the comment then surely all comments thereafter must be from downvoters. Even if I did downvote the post I will prepend "I haven't voted on this yet, but ..." with my suggestion for improvement / or my "guess" as to why the post may have been downvoted by other users.

Comment: I suppose the same could be achieved with "I refuse to disclose my confidential voting habits and will neither confirm nor deny that I have or have not voted on any specific post. With that said, I think your post could be improved if you..."

Comment: @TinyGiant So, just skip the preamble and start with “I think your post could be improved if you…”? If the OP still feels hostility after such a neutral comment… well, you can’t fix people. ‍♂️

Comment: @deceze did you miss the _"The comment itself is a trap for all future commenters, because if no one was explaining anything before the comment then surely all comments thereafter must be from downvoters."_ in my first comment?

Answer (score 23):

Regardless of whether you downvoted, or whether you feel like commenting, do flag the comment for removal. **No longer needed** flags are usually honoured in these cases, as well as on plain undirected "why the downvote?". If the comment is deemed as more provocative towards the user(s) who downvoted (*"some trolls downvoted my question for no reason"*, *"whoever downvoted should be banned from this site"*), you are in your right to escalate to the **Unfriendly or Unkind** flag. Yes, they might be upset and in need of venting for what may be felt as an unfair demotion of their content, but such an exhibition of impatience is not only noise to visitors, but also makes potential contributors to that question feel uncomfortable, and will drive them away.

There is indeed a chance that the poster of the subsequent comment becomes a target, and what happens next is not always predictable. Best case: everyone acts in good faith, the OP thanks the user and improves the question/answer with that in mind (if that is possible at all; downvotes are also frequent on unsalvageable questions). Bad case: the OP starts an endless argument with you on how the question is appropriate, leading to more noise and frustration. Worst case: you receive an e-mail accusing you of bashing people that are still learning and of not being a real programmer, even though your comment was constructive.

I have experienced each of these outcomes so far, and yet the consequences of facing a negative reaction far outweigh the ones from good reactions. The life of a Stack Overflow curator that leaves replies to "why the downvote?" will generally have to show some resilience, otherwise they might just "break" after the eventual Nth bad case.

In conclusion, replying to such comments is a bit like playing the roulette, where the stakes are based on the OP's question/answer and mood. It's such a strange game.
The only move that always leaves you unharmed is not to play. Whether you're willing to continue placing bets is up to you. [No one should feel obligated to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin), after all.

Comment: _Russian_ roulette, then

Comment: _"Bad case: the OP starts an endless argument with you on how the question is appropriate, leading to more noise and frustration."_ that's what I have experienced

Comment: 'Would you like to play a game?  Global thermonuclear war, or explaining downvotes on SO?'

Comment: @MartinJames [Giant Meteor 2020](https://twitter.com/votegiantmeteor)

Answer (score 14):

No, you shouldn't. Let's nail it down,
imagine yourself asking:

> did you downvote my answer?

it's pretty obvious you are not focused on the topic and you are angry for reputation. Even though you discover who was the guy that downvoted your answer what you achieve? what would change?

Don't answer. It would be like answering in real life to one asking if you were looking at his girlfriend.

I want to bring to you my personal experience: I always get a lot of downvotes but I don't care because many times people explain to me where I am wrong and I find myself upvoting comments or answers that goes against what I said because if you ask or reply with the right attitude you will accept downvotes and replies that are legit (even though I see too much strictness sometimes...).

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't you say if you down-voted them?

- They may take it personally, and may down-vote your answers because you down-voted theirs.  The purpose of down-voting is to get the right answers to people quicker, not to battle against other users. Some people will take it personally and will retaliate.
- A feeling of anonymity is important in getting honest answers from people.  If people knew who was voting, then people would be less inclined to answer honestly because of fear of repercussions to themselves.

If they ask you a question like this again, just say the voting is meant to be anonymous for some good reasons. (and you could restate the reasons above).

At least that is what I would do.

Comment: Stack overflow automatically disqualifies votes when one user upvotes/downvotes one person's questions/answers a lot more than any others.

Comment: This is good to know.  They probably thought of this problem years ago.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd The point is, you shouldn't have to suffer those downvotes in the *first* place.  Which is why explaining a downvote, yours or others, does nothing but paint a target on your back.  All it does is add aggravation to your day.  Invariably, the requester isn't actually looking to improve; they're just looking for something to attack, either your argument, or you yourself.

Comment: If they do that, it would be worth contacting a moderator.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd You're missing the point.  It's not worth the trouble to risk it.  Just downvote and move on.  If someone asks for justification, ignore it.  No problems with painting a target on your back, or having to defend your position.

Comment: @fbueckert I understand the point you are making, but it is opinion-based whether it is worth the risk. If you do reveal that you were the downvoter, and they purposely downvote your posts, then you can show a moderator that you revealed to them you were the downvoter and that they were downvoting your posts and prove your case easily.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd It's still additional effort that shouldn't be required.  You're dismissing the concern as if it's no trouble at all to just let yourself be targetted, which is missing the entire issue.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not dismissing the issue, I am just saying that it is not a very big concern.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd Which is dismissing it.  I disagree entirely.

Comment: @fbueckert That's not dismissing it, that's just pointing out that it should not be a high priority, and the comment I posted before that showed how to deal with it if it ever occurs.

Answer (score -10):

I think that there is no general rule to that as it heavily depends on context.
Per se, you don't know *why* the question was asked.

Suppose the downvoted answer got a lot of critical comments. Maybe the answer's author just wants to know which comment he should address or consider first or foremost.

Maybe he/she feels the downvote was unjustified.

I personally would answer truthfully, and maybe add some reasoning for the downvote, if I did not already do that adequately in the comments. But I would also rethink whether the downvote truly was justified.

Only if the other person tries to go into an argument rather than a sensible discussion about the answer's topic, I would shut the conversation down.

Comment: If the answer already has comments, why should someone need to ask who did the downvoting? Why would that influence the order at which those issues are addressed?

Comment: Well, a downvote is a stronger statement in terms of evaluation. So, if there were multiple critical comments to an answer, it appears to me that it adds information to know which specific critique led to a downvote.

Answer (score -14):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem

**- 100 % Compliance**

- Flag the comment as **It's unfriendly or unkind. This comment is rude or condescending.**

**Bit Lenient but still compliant**

- Reply with just "Yes" and explain the reason
- If he asks for Further questions , Flag the comment as **It's no longer needed.
  This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.**

General thumb rule. Make sure you dont violate the code of conduct at the same time, you have 100% person right to report any incident to moderators. They can decide and act on it.

As mentioned by some people above. Single person grudge will not affect you in this forum. He may purposely downvote your answers even if its good. But he cannot stop you from getting up votes.

Moreover, it practically impossible for some one to follow you in Stack Overflow, as there is not follow user option.

Comment: I wouldn't say the comment should be flagged as *unfriendly or unkind*.  `No longer needed` will be sufficient.

Answer (score -26):

Yes, I think the best thing is to reply in a helpful manner in two specific situations:

1. The person asking is clearly new to Stack Overflow

   or
2. He/she wants to know **why** they were downvoted and **NOT who** downvoted them.

I usually reply with the  appropriate link from [i-downvoted-because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) and the Stack Overflow guide on how to ask a good question: *[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*

For example, if the OP made no attempt to solve the problem first, I would put that in my reply and include this link: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

I think not letting someone know why they were downvoted only creates resentment towards the community.

Comment: And letting someone know who downvoted them causes resentment against them, instead.  There are going to be *vanishingly* few users who will accept feedback, and will instead take downvotes personally.

Comment: I agree that trying to help is best. But experience has taught me that telling them that you down voted isn't often helpful. These days I try to explain what's wrong with the question in a friendly way, then down vote later if they did nothing about it. That way I try to help, and I stay anonymous.

Comment: "not letting someone know why they were downvoted" isn't the same as "not letting someone know that _you_ downvoted them", which I agree, is a very bad move.

Comment: *I think not letting someone know why they were downvoted...* But the OP *doesn't* know why the down vote happened; they weren't the ones to down vote. They only suggested improvements.

Comment: I would consider that valid suggestion for questions/answers by 100K+ users as you generally expect positive engagement in such cases (also such users would not ask "*if* you downvoted"). For everyone else it is unlikely to improve anything.

Comment: Side note: before leaving links to idownvoteddbecau.se make sure to read corresponding meta discussions (TL;DR: it considered noise/not welcome in many cases)

Comment: I find resentment to be a bit like fire. If given plenty of fuel it can spread. In that vein, comments responding to why someone took an action that they disagreed with as simply supplying plenty more fuel. No one's looking for clarity in those discussions. They're looking for a punching bag. Don't become one.

Comment: @fbueckert It is not the *person* being downvoted, it is the answer which has the downvote.

Comment: @Makoto _"They're looking for a punching bag"_, yeah, that's what it is

Comment: If you don't help people doing better - you aren't helping. There is no guarantee you are improving the quality of their comments by replying them. But - there at least is a chance to do so and if you don't try to help others - why are you at stackoverflow at all?

Comment: @GunterKönigsmann We may well be here to answer questions that have value to the site without requiring substantial improvements. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: fbueckert's point is that the people whose answers get downvoted take the downvotes personally.

Comment: @Makoto you say "No one's looking for clarity in those discussions."  That's pretty cynical, and incorrect.   I've certainly had many experiences in which I give what I think is a good question, or answer, and it gets downvoted; in that case I'll certainly I'll desire clarity and I'm inclined to ask why people are downvoting.   I'm less likely to ask, these days, though, because I now know it's likely to be interpreted as hostile, that is, that "I'm looking for a punching bag" as you say.

Comment: @DonHatch: There's a big difference asking "Why did I get downvoted" or asking "Who did downvote me". The first one (might) ask for help improving the question. The second one looks for someone to blame.

Comment: Ok...own up, who downvoted me !!  :)

Comment: @Nick Looks like it's **flagging time**! :)

Comment: @Nick I did! ;-) Mind you, there's a difference between using [i-downvoted-because](//idownvotedbecau.se/) on a newbie, and doing so/otherwise engaging an established user. For a newbie, there is only the possibility that it might be helpful, with almost no risk of retaliation. For an established user, there is almost no chance that it is helpful and the risk of retaliation is not worth it. I myself have used idownvotedbecau.se, though strictly only on newbies. If you change your answer so it applies *only* in the case of newbies, then I'll reverse my downvote ;-)

Comment: lol  @robinCTS - good point, thanks for explaining. ill edit the answer !

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @SirGoPythonJavaCppRubythe3rd **No.**

Comment: @E_net4 why? i clarified the answer

Comment: @Nick It is still the question most disagreed with, which makes it the worst candidate for acceptance.

Answer (score -30):

Yes you should, this is a prime opportunity to explain why you downvoted and how the question could be better.

Comment: This is a prime opportunity to _walk away_. Note that the OP did not even downvote in this case, and had already provided some feedback.

Comment: And be down voted or argued with for your trouble. No, thank you.

Comment: What @fbueckert said. While this may be true in principle, in practice more often than not the question is asked in bad faith and the asker is simply looking for a reason to scapegoat the voter or otherwise retaliate, should the explanation be unsatisfactory.

Comment: @BoltClock Generally *every* explanation is unsatisfactory.  The number of times that question is asked in good faith is vanishingly small.  Most often, it's just there to give the commentor a target.