# Is there some canonical "Why downvotes are not evil?"

Tags: discussion, downvotes, behavior

I would like to be nicer to new users. Let me try to make my point by quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/4117728):

> Contrary to popular opinion, most users here are nice and want to help
>   rather than enjoying "shooting down" newbies' questions with downvotes
>   to make them feel bad and unwelcome.

Then on downvotes (emphasis mine):

> Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system. **Rather
>   than being a way of communicating with the poster**, they are a way of
>   communicating to future readers that a question or answer is not
>   interesting or useful. If someone wants to leave a comment to
>   communicate with the poster, they can always do so, independent of the
>   voting system.

And this is where my perception differs from the ideal case described by Pekka 웃. Downvotes (and close votes) **are** too often considered as a way of communicating **by** the poster. In some regards I am a newbie myself and I remember quite well how it feels to get a rain of downvotes and the question closed within minutes while you don't understand a thing.

I do not want to feel bad for downvoting questions of new users, because I do not downvote to punish the questioner. To my understanding, leaving a comment to explain the downvote is part of what makes the site work. Often this is still considered as offensive and I have no clue what to reply in that case. For me there is little correlation between wanting to help the questioner and up/downvoting.

Are users penalized for getting their questions downvoted? (I have to ask because I am not 100% certain, and other than the reputation of course.)

**What is the best way to communicate that downvoting is not a hostile act?**

I am missing a more elaborated "My question got downvoted, does this mean Stack Overflow hates me? - NO! Don't panic. We **do want** to help you." in [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) or something similar.

PS: I didn't follow the "be nice" campaign to closely, so if you think I am completely missing the point, just let me know ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be productive to go around posting a link like that on any post you downvote.  You're just putting a big target on your back by announching yourself as a downvoter of the post, and thus giving the author (and potentially others) a person to direct all of their frustration at the downvotes towards, and they're also *very* unlikely to go and read the link there at all, and if they do, they're likely not going to be in a mood that makes them very receptive to its message.  Just about anyone who would have gotten upset and acted inappropriately with no comment would do so even with it.

Comment: @DavyM ah that question is about downvotes on meta specifically

Comment: You...don't *seem* to be new to Meta.  Not sure how that's at all relevant to the current situation, though

Comment: @Servy I dont want a link to post around everytime i downvote (links to the help are used like that commonly btw). I would like to have a link when I feel I need it

Comment: @user463035818, The question title specifically says "on the main site." That refers to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @fbueckert i think its my second maybe third question here, but yeah not relevant at all ;)

Comment: @user463035818 And what situations did you have in mind?

Comment: @user463035818 Your questions are all listed on your profile.  This is your fifth undeleted question.

Comment: @Servy the situation when a new user explains me that leaving a comment to explain why I downvoted is hostile / not nice / whatever. I dont have examples at hand, typically such questions get closed

Comment: @user463035818 Then that's exactly the type of situation where you shouldn't be posting it.  Just flag their comments and stop posting.  Someone is just angry and looking for people to lash out at.  You're making yourself a target and that person is *very* unlikely to actually respond positively to a comment like you've described.

Comment: @Servy partly agree, because not making a target is often the best option. Partly dont agree, because I wish someone told me more clearly that downvotes are not evil when I was new

Comment: Additionally, [this advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375534/1197934) is going to help you quite a bit.

Comment: @user463035818 And were you rudely lashing out at other people when your posts were downvoted?  Did other people explain the purpose of downvotes *at that time* and help you realize it, or were you either a) more constructive from the start or b) came to understand the value in downvotes at a later point in time when you weren't currently upset at a post of yours being downvoted.

Comment: @fbueckert actually now I realize that too often I do disclose whether I did downvote or not. Maybe I should change that....

Comment: @Servy mostly b ;). Actually I do prefer to get told where I am wrong rather than getting upvotes (I dont really learn much from an upvote). Thanks a lot for your input, really helped me to make up my mind

Comment: Yeah usually going at it from a 'heres what would make this question better' ends up sending the same message, without announcing yourself as a downvoter