# Is asking for "how to improve the question" a reason to delete a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

One of my questions ([Scatter plot with colored markers + colormap in ECharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715577/scatter-plot-with-colored-markers-colormap-in-echarts)) got a couple of downvotes, and I was asking in a comment what I can do to improve the question.

Today I noticed that my comment got deleted, and I got further downvotes without explanations. Today I reposted my comment:

> @Downvoters: What can I do to improve the question? The same type of question gets asked for many other plotting libraries, and typically it is well received on SO. I simply don't know where to start because ECharts seems to use a different terminology to other plotting libraries.

Is such a comment not allowed?

I'm honestly surprised by the downvotes, because in other communities (other plotting libraries) this would have been a standard question. I'm even more surprised that such a comment gets deleted without a notification/explanation why.

---

From my perspective, this question is not a duplicate of the question [whether giving feedback is mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). I knew that it isn't, so reading the answers of that question wouldn't help me.

What wasn't clear to me is why the rule of non-mandatory feedback implies that a comment asking for improvement suggestions can be flagged and deleted. This has nothing to do with the motivation of why a mandatory system hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Agree with @yivi since `@Downvoters` makes it look more like a complaint than a request for information on how to improve. Also, it is best to avoid the "but Billy's mom lets him do it" type of argument since each question must fly or fail on its own merits.

Comment: Side note: I'm no expert on EChart and so won't vote on the question that generated this meta question, but to me, it appears 1) very broad, and 2) lacks evidence of demonstrable prior research into the issue and possible solutions. You definitely can improve that question. And I mean *concrete* evidence, not the "I have searched everywhere..." throw-out phrase.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Jumping between communities a lot, I find the differences in handling questions quite surprising though.

Comment: yes, this site handles questions quite differently, likely due to the sheer volume of questions posted on this site daily and especially due to the sheer volume of *bad* questions that have to be handled. It's not easy to ask a good question on this site, I'm afraid.

Comment: Side note 2: and while as stated, I am not voting on your question on the main site, you will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stack overflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: Also: if someone wants to leave a comment on how to improve your question, they'll provide it. Calling out downvoters and asking them to, while explaining how their votes are inappropriate, will lead to nothing good in my experience (even if the votes were actually inappropriate). The mods have probably only done you a service by removing the comment, but you've undone that by bringing even more critical eyes to a question that doesn't demonstrate research effort (note the downvote tooltip _this question does not show research effort_)

Comment: @ErikAI spend ~an hour on that question, but this is one of the cases where I really don't know how to show it. Should I post unrelated  code just to "prove" effort? I thought the question is more to the point by keeping it short. I'm looking for the **concept** in ECharts that will allow me to get started :(.

Comment: I would venture that, no you shouldn't post unrelated code, but rather probably need to do more research (API, similar questions,...) so that the question itself is more specific. You may be asking at too soon a spot in your efforts for this site.

Comment: Well, at least don't start with _skimmed the docs_... See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7296893). You can also show code that is in the vicinity of your objective, such as a simple scatterplot, so people know you can load data, can work with your variable names, etc.

Comment: @ErikA I tried to do that now, I'm not sure if it improves the question though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I flag any comment requesting an explanation for downvotes that I come across. That one might be one of them, although I am unable to recall every single case of flagged content. When receiving a downvote, see what else can be improved in the post without calling the downvotes out.

Comment: this is why I suggested blocking @downvoters the same as lmgty links, it reeks of aggressive behavior justified/disguised as *politeness* or passive-aggressive behavior at best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson but what if someone uses the "downvoters" nickname? :) How would you be able to tag that person in "@dowvoters" is blocked? :)

Comment: You've improved your question well imo! Looks like we can see the positive site of the meta effect for once, a pretty rare occurrence.

Comment: @ErikA In what way, to your eyes, is the question better than revision 1? It's *longer*, but as far as I can see it hasn't become clearer, changed in scope, or become in any way more answerable.

Comment: @MarkAmery There are multiple reasons, imo. As an answerer, I know the OP can make basic plots so don't need to repeat the basics, I can copy the question code and demonstrate the changes needed instead of writing an entirely separate piece of code, and the goal is even more clear imo. As a person looking into scatterplots and hitting this question in Google, I might even not want coloured markers, and the provided code might be sufficient. I often skip questions not demonstrating research effort, because after a basic answer I often get a follow-up with _where do I paste this_.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I really don't see why this should be a duplicate. The thing I wanted to find out was **why was my comment deleted**. I was wondering if I had accidentally used strong language or so (not being a native speaker). My first search on Meta was exactly that phrase, but that didn't help. The question (+ answers) you linked doesn't touch the topic of comment deletion at all, and would not have helped me at all to answer my question.

Comment: @bluenote10 the important thing to remember is that ANYTHING you do will be wrong in someone's eyes. Try not to take it personally, no matter how idiotic the criticism may seem. This site is confusing to newbies, and even long-term users are often baffled by the byzantine and often self-contradictory customs and rules. It takes practice.

Comment: @ErikA I agree with the "copy the question code" part (if the answer happen to be similar), but "the provided code might be sufficient" doesn't make the question useful *as a question*.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Asking for help improving a post is fine. But asking for users to explain their votes is noisy and prone to lead to unproductive arguments.

You'll get better luck with your comments if you ask the same **without referring** to *"@Downvoters"*. Anyone can help you improve the question, not only users that voted on it.

By asking "downvoters" for feedback it certainly reads like asking users to explain their votes. Just ask for specific feedback on your post, leave votes altogether out.  Comments asking for vote explanations are routinely deleted.

There is no guarantee anyone would post a response, but it's less likely your comment will be flagged/deleted

Comment: _Comments asking for vote explanations are routinely deleted._ Out of curiosity: Has this policy changed over time? I remember seeing such questions a lot in the past and mostly leading to helpful discussions. I also vaguely remember that SO (or someone on SO) gave me a hint like "instead of downvoting, consider commenting how to improve the question". Has this ever been an official guideline that has been dropped over time?

Comment: @bluenote10 Take a look at this: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408) A comment showing how a post can be improved when downvoting is sometimes helpful, but not mandatory. And bad or not useful content should always be downvoted.

Comment: @bluenote10 See Q&As like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) or [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375534/a-person-asked-me-did-you-downvote-my-answer-should-i-reply?noredirect=1&lq=1). Basically, commenting on a post, good. Commenting on votes, bad.

Comment: Such comments are almost immediately "no longer needed", because the users you're asking are likely long gone and never going to come back.

Comment: I've hesitated to provide feedback on a question many times for fear of being attacked as a down-voter.

Comment: I've (probably mistakenly) in the past responded to such question in apology for downvoters, trying to point the OP towards ways they could improve their post.  In the majority of circumstances, this feedback was taken poorly.  Perhaps it was a result of a lack of grace on my part, but the feeling I have gotten is, most of the time, when somebody is mad at downvoters, they don't want help improving; they want to be mad.

Comment: I don't agree with this. Having "@Downvoters" in the comment is valuable because it makes clear that the comment is being made in response to negative feedback. Without that, to a visitor who sees the comment and doesn't have the privilege required to see that there have been downvotes, the comment's presence will be confusing. Why, that visitor will wonder, is this crazy person randomly asking what's wrong with their question in the absence of any indication that there's something wrong with it?

Comment: Asking for help is the same thing as asking why the downvote, no matter how you spin it.    If you don't understand the reason for the downvote, it makes it look capricious or personal. I've had a question where it was downvoted to -1, I added a comment asking "Why the downvote, how can I improve?" (or similar), it was deleted by a mod because I'm not allowed to ask. So how COULD I improve my question? I just gave up, not worth my time.

Answer (score 5):

Asking how to improve a (badly received) question is absolutely the right thing to do. It shows you are actually interested in improving the quality of your contributions. With the sole exception of "@Downvoters" the inappropriateness of which has already explained in comments and the answer of yivi, your comment reads okay to me. You clearly ask for directions and give a bit more context. If I were a mod, I might have considered only deleting the "@Downvoters" and leaving the rest of the comment there or commenting a bit on why the comment was deleted.

I recommend you to edit "The same type of question gets asked for many other plotting libraries. I simply don't know where to start because ECharts seems to use a different terminology to other plotting libraries." into the question and leave "What can I do to improve the question? Any help is greatly appreciated." as a comment below it. A comment like this should not get deleted.

If you cannot further improve the question and it remains negatively scored and you really want to know why it wasn't that good, you could ask on meta about why it was received badly.

Answer (score -5):

I think  “how to improve the question” is a great question in the context of commenting on the posted-question.  There may be things that are technology or language specific.  Perhaps more code needs to be posted (especially in 3-tiered web development).  Perhaps there are grammar issues that could be cleared up.  I think it's a fine way to find out how to improve a question.

Comment: Feedback on a question should probably be posted as comment below the question itself, not as answer to a meta question asking why comments asking for clarification of downvotes are deleted. I know this sounds rather complicated, but your answer here doesn't answer this question here. Just post it at the original question.

Comment: @Trilarion -- please see the edit.  Apparently 'question' was questionable here, and therefore, of question, but I meant the question:  'how to improve the question', which itself is a question.