# Is it appropriate to comment '... and I didn't downvote your post'?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes

Is it appropriate to comment the error of an answer, and add --- 'and I didn't downvote your post'?

A user stated that in their comment to my answer, which had a -1 score. I don't think it's necessary, what about the community?

Comment: It shows that retaliation votes is a serous fear among commenters ... :(

Comment: In many cases, the first person to comment after a post is down voted, is assumed by the OP to be the one who down-voted. So many append that disclaimer to avoid retaliation.

Comment: @rene Exactly, that's my thought too.

Comment: @Nkosi That will a red flag to the answerer that the commenter thinks he/she will retaliate without the disclaimer.

Comment: It is not personal. It happens quite frequently. scenario: a hi-rep poster receives negative attention. you comment on the post then hey, look down vote. coincidence? I think not. You'd be surprised.

Comment: @Nkosi What does the answerer being hi-rep have to do with your senario?

Comment: You can only down vote on answers once you have attained a certain amount of rep. But many tend to covet that rep and wont waste it on down voting answers. Only after reaching a higher rep do you tend to see the retaliation votes. (Based on my experience, of course) and even then they will target more your questions and not your answers.

Comment: See also: [A person asked me “did you downvote my answer?” Should I reply?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375534/a-person-asked-me-did-you-downvote-my-answer-should-i-reply). One of the answers suggests appending that expression to a comment.

Comment: It is not necessary, and borderline inappropriate. No one should discuss their votes. I either delete these comments or edit out the portion about votes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is inappropriate. It is more the result of a sad consequence that some of the commenters / curators are met with a flurry of down votes on their own posts when they try to work with the OP to make their content better.

In an ideal world no-one on the SE network should be worried about retaliation. If you see however users that leave those precautionary warnings we might be a little bit more supportive than we normally would. Let's start to respond positively to their feedback.
That should send a signal that having fear on this site should not be a normal mode of operation. Responding well to critique also teaches others how to deal in a good way with feedback.

We can only teach by example. Let's be nice and become the community that the code of conduct wants us to be. Give it 6 to 8 weeks before everyone gets the message. Don't give up!

Comment: The "flurry of down votes" got me thinking.

Comment: @AnnZen Would you like to expand on that? In case it isn't clear, the description of this flurry is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes).

Comment: I know what it means, I meant the thought haven't crossed my mind before.

Comment: Sadly enough, it does happen, as well as name calling and sometimes even off-site harassment.

Comment: This is one of my favorite answers of yours.