# The Stack Overflow community has turned sour on most questions these days

Tags: discussion, downvotes, community

I have been asking questions on Stack Overflow for over 10 years. I can summarize my experience like this:

- My top ranked questions are easy things you can easily look up on documentation sites, like "RegExp.escape for JS" or "How to install dev dependencies with npm", type stuff. I get points for these several times a week for years.
- My most pressing and important personal questions are either complex algorithm questions which I can barely attempt to solve, or deep in the weeds debugging on some production complex piece of an application's logic.

I have many other types of questions as well.

But the past few years I have been receiving downvotes for almost every one of my "tough algorithm questions" or "complex logic debugging questions", without any comments; people are just generally rude. If I were Stack Overflow, I would want to know that the community really is making people like me feel bad in the stomach, like there is so much hate in the world. Most people respond harshly and negatively, with downvotes and votes to close almost instantly and without any support or helpful discussion.

Can this sort of behavior be changed, or is it too late for the Stack Overflow community?

I almost at this point *can't ask any important questions* on the site. People tear me this way and that on how to ask "better questions" in rude ways, yet one person says this, and the other person says the opposite. I can't please all sides; it's impossible. And trying to work nicely together with rude teammates just makes things not that fun to deal with anymore. Is it just me, or can something be done here about this? There are too many examples of this to flag each one, but it happens several times each day.

It is extremely rare (happened only 2 or 3 times probably in my 10+ years here) where people are actually nice and helpful and trying to work with me to get my question answered. I would like to see more of that, but I don't know where to begin in getting there, hence this post as a sort of "retro" thought. Action item: be nice to people pouring their heart out into their questions, trying to learn and solve important problems in their life. Help them get their question answered, even if you personally think it's too hard of a problem for your wheelhouse. It doesn't mean you have to silently downvote it. That sort of stuff.

My "top question", which everyone finds so useful, would probably get shut down in an instant if asked today. I think it's funny what people really find valuable, and what the SO community at large finds valuable (and how it is a constantly changing target, despite the attempts at standardizing community rules).

Comment: "My most pressing and important personal questions are either complex algorithm questions which I can barely attempt to solve, or deep in the weeds debugging on some production complex piece of an app's logic." - 1) The former are most likely too hard to expect an answer to ... because ... well ... it is too much to expect smart people to do a lot of hard work for you for free.   2) The latter are unlikely to be of any interest to anyone but yourself ... and the chances are that you can't provide all of the necessary information for debugging them anyway.  And debugging is hard, etc; see 1).

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow is reaching the point where all of the good (i.e. on-topic, interesting, answerable, etc) questions have already been asked and answered.  But yes, standards have changed.

Comment: @StephenC - there's a certain amount of truth to what you said but also bear in mind that as technologies change and evolve there will always be new opportunities for useful, interesting questions.

Comment: There's nothing rude about voting. Votes are not for you. They are just an indication of what the community values.

Comment: I am not surprised that complex personal questions get downvotes. That's exactly how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Please don't expect people to work with you and help you improve your question. There are too many questions to try and salvage each one. Many will be deleted without an answer.

Comment: I looked at your recent questions, and you’re violating site rules/guidelines. You’re asking duplicate questions, posting code in links to other sites, etc. This is a burden on the curators of this site. Please don’t do this.

Comment: I didn’t see the comments being much rude. For instance, asking you to provide an MRE inside the question is not rude, when you failed to provide one. And if people would be snarky? You have so much reputation that it’s annoying to see you not understand how to format your questions correctly.

Comment: *"My most pressing and important questions"* how "pressing" or "important" question are *to you* is irrelevant. Often *because* the OP wants a "fast" but complex answer they end up being *bad* questions. [So] isn't a helpdesk and the users here are under no obligation to even read your question, let alone answer it; expecting a quick solution is only going to end up in disappointment or worse (from your employer). If you are in need of a quick and informed solution to a difficult problem then paying someone is almost always going to yield *far* better results. We are volunteers here.

Comment: [1,136 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169992/lance?tab=questions) suggests a certain way of using Stack Overflow and a certain expectation of Stack Overflow. How would you (or somebody else) describe it? Are they all so specialised questions that they aren't duplicates? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Comment: If you want to ask why *your own* questions are badly received, I can think of some reasons… but framing it in terms of “Why is Stack Overflow so mean” is not going to help you get any concrete feedback.

Comment: Not only volunteers, but often skilled and experienced engineers who know that debugging of complex software systems is VERY DIFFICULT when you have direct access to the bug, ie. requirements, design, code, compiler, linker, make, hardware, OS, debugger, logs, environment, network, peers etc.  It is near impossible to debug by text exchange over a Q&A site.  I am tired of explaining that writing code is easy, trivial even, compared with the full software development.  I am tired of OP's disbelief that, despite building with no errors, apps still don't do what they want or expode with AV's:(

Comment: Do you think *complex algorithm questions which I can barely attempt to solve, or deep in the weeds debugging on some production complex piece of an application's logic* questions are likely to help future programmers searching for a solution to their problem?

Comment: The fact that this got so many negative downvotes gives you all the information you need to know. And of course someone will delete this comment to make it seem like everything's fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what do down-votes on this meta question have to do with the point that you're trying to make above. You're seeing by this voting pattern that a subsection of members of the site disagree with many of your statements. Again, maybe I'm dense, but how does whether this small community agrees with you or not establish your point? Please elaborate.

Comment: Also, your meta question is purportedly about the "sourness" of this site. So, rather than address any of the comments made, you've posted your own comment that is somewhat, well..., sour. Why? If you wish the site to be more productive and less sour, why not start with the one member that you have the most influence on, yourself?

Comment: There aren't any "negative downvotes" here, @Lance, because votes don't have any else attached to them; there's no negative downvotes and there are no positive downvotes. They all have the same value; there's no negativity or positively attached to them. Once would hope you understood that with the amount of reputation you have, but you've only ever cast *65* downvotes... It seems you aren't making use of them and/or don't understand what they are.

Comment: *"And of course someone will delete this comment to make it seem like everything's fine."* This has a somewhat sour taste to it; for someone trying to suggest the site is sour, isn't it a bit ironic that youre contributing to the "sour taste"?

Comment: "But the past few years I have been receiving downvotes for almost every one of my "tough algorithm questions" or "complex logic debugging questions"" Your **questions** have been receiving such downvotes, because they **do not meet current policies and guidelines**. They should also be getting votes to close as "needs more focus"; if not, it could be because there aren't enough people around in the relevant tags with 3000+ reputation. If you've been seeing those, it should have explained the problem to you already.

Comment: "People tear me this way and that on how to ask "better questions" in rude ways, yet one person says this, and the other person says the opposite." Please show me a concrete example where you believe this has happened, and I'll be happy to explain how it is supposed to work. I have high confidence a priori that you are not actually being told contradictory things (they only seem contradictory from your viewpoint) and that nobody here would agree with you that people are being rude. (If you really think people are being rude in comments, **please flag it**.)

Comment: "My "top question", which everyone finds so useful, would probably get shut down in an instant if asked today." Because it would almost certainly be a duplicate by now, yes. But there is **definitely not** any policy against questions being "easy" or something that can be "looked up on other sites".

Comment: Here is my recommendation if you want to try your most recent question again: start with the following exact four words: "I have this code:". Then, show code that someone else could **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, to demonstrate the **exact** problem you are asking about, **directly**. Then describe in full sentences exactly what that problem is. Finally, ask a question, starting with a question word like "how" or "why", and ending with a question mark.

Comment: For example: when you say things like "Here is a demo showing the bounding box on one of the SVG images", this does not explain: what should the bounding box be instead, and why? How is that different from the actual result? Aesthetically, what is wrong with the output text?

Comment: "The fact that this got so many negative downvotes gives you all the information you need to know." Yes; it shows that we share an understanding of how the site works that you are refusing to accept, despite having it explained repeatedly.

Comment: What @KarlKnechtel is telling you. Strongly suggest you reduce the scope of this question from "SO has gone sour" down to "Tell me how to improve this [text scaling question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020813/how-can-i-get-this-text-layout-algorithm-to-properly-scale-the-text-to-font-siz)"? (Answers: a) no clear question stated b) no MRE (the 'M' stands for Minimal c) Aggressively trim your example down to the absolute minimum. One part of one sentence should be enough/"Less is More". d) the whole thing is four screenfuls long!)

Answer (score 3):

> I  have been asking questions on Stack Overflow for over 10 years.

Better keep in mind that you participated on Stack Overflow during its thriving years, when each new question asked was more likely to be novel and useful, and there were less concerns of open-ended questions saturating the platform.

Over time, we learned that open ended questions create an aura of vagueness which does not help future visitors finding what they want, and may even attract spam.
Nowadays, several thousands of questions are asked each day, at a much greater rate than the emergence of new technologies. A question is much more likely to have already been asked before, or more likely to be well covered by the technology or its official resources. While this is not a reason to exclude content, it may serve grounds for people voting it as less useful.

> But the past few years I have been receiving downvotes for almost every one of my "tough algorithm questions" or "complex logic debugging questions", without any comments; people are just generally rude

Voting is paramount to the platform, and it is [intentionally anonymous and frictionless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777). If you cannot bear the possibility of receiving some downvotes over subpar quality, then that is a problem which cannot simply be put on the shoulders of Stack Overflow itself of its community. You need to take votes calmly, not personally. One can start by not calling people rude when they vote. It is disrespectful and suggests that people should be subjected to abuse (there are many questions here on Meta about voting and its anonymous nature: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375534) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686) [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393913)).

Some folks in the comments have already provided some hints as to why *"tough algorithm questions"* or *"complex logic debugging questions"* may be problematic on Stack Overflow, so you could have just asked about this here!

> Can this sort of behavior be changed, or is it too late for the Stack Overflow community?

Again, the behavior of the community had to change once the site turned into a big city. If some people have issues with how moderation and curation is done, then that may be a sign that those people need to adapt or move to smaller cities. Catering the needs of such askers would have been detrimental to a much larger scale of people who want to continue using Stack Overflow as a reliable, high quality library.

Regardless of this, you can always seek feedback on whether a question is suitable for the platform, and/or whether it can be adjusted to fit. Note that this is very different from storming the door and calling the community sour when your content is poorly received.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this sort of behavior be changed, or is it too late for the Stack Overflow community?

Nobody can look into the future, but I take the optimistic stance here that it is never too late really and any sort of behavior can in principle be changed always.

> Is it just me, or can something be done here about this?

That is the more difficult question. What you report (lots of downvotes, not many people wanting to engage with you) hints something isn't working. Again, the optimistic stance would be that if something should be done about it it also can be done.

We should always

- discuss the meaning and benefits of the rules guiding Stack Overflow on meta
- pay attention to meticulously implementing them, i.e. only downvoting content that merits it, and so on...

So much for the meta feedback to your meta question. I also looked at some specific questions and I partly see what you mean. Some questions of yours with score -1 could have in my opinion also score 0 or score +1 but one also needs to mention that at very low numbers of votes they might be distributed somewhat stochastically, i.e. the score is only a good indicator of usefulness in the limit of large numbers. Maybe people really should spend more time on analyzing questions before voting.

---

I looked at your last 30 questions. Out of that 9 have currently a negative score, 5 have a positive and 16 have score 0. The large amount of zero scored questions is somewhat typical for SO if I remember correctly, they are simply not yet evaluated. And I should say that I'm not a web developer.

I think the question [How can I get this text layout algorithm to properly scale the text to "font size" option (text made with SVG paths)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020813/how-can-i-get-this-text-layout-algorithm-to-properly-scale-the-text-to-font-siz) seems like a valid programming question to me and the score of -8 exaggerated. Initially there wasn't a demo but now there is.

Some questions which I couldn't really evaluate given my lack of domain knowledge.

[How to rotate a regular polygon of arbitrary sides so it is oriented pointing up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817810/how-to-rotate-a-regular-polygon-of-arbitrary-sides-so-it-is-oriented-pointing-up) looks like a math question to me. The code probably works fine but one needs to find the angle that makes your polygons look nice (i.e. with one side flat at the bottom), which is more a math problem.

[General approach to showing indicator that page is loading in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75810823/general-approach-to-showing-indicator-that-page-is-loading-in-next-js) seems to ask for opinions ("What is the recommended approach?") when it should just ask for a solution and it does not show any (re)search.

[How can I generate all possible melody strings for this melody generator, minus the duplicates offset by some number of beats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75598430/how-can-i-generate-all-possible-melody-strings-for-this-melody-generator-minus) is quite a big task to ask for and does not show any research, but also an example of a well asked question. I upvoted the question.